# 502 Bad gateway : node app on container port 5000

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

I have hosted an angular app as a Microservice in aws here : http://test-2079808347.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:5000. I'm getting a 502 Bad Gateway error. Given below is the yaml template of the service and the Task definition. The image I'm using is working in the local environment when I run `docker run -p 5000:5000 <image-tag>`

```
    Resources:
      Service:
        Type: AWS::ECS::Service
        DependsOn: ListenerRule
        Properties:
          Cluster: !Ref Cluster
          Role: !Ref ServiceRole
          DesiredCount: !Ref DesiredCount
          TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition
          LoadBalancers:
            - ContainerName: "website-service"
              ContainerPort: 5000
              TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup

      TaskDefinition:
        Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
        Properties:
          Family: website-service
          ContainerDefinitions:
            - Name: website-service
              Essential: true
              Image: registry.hub.docker.com/abameerdeen/activity_service:latest
              Memory: 128
              Environment:
                - Name: PRODUCT_SERVICE_URL
                  Value: !Ref ProductServiceUrl
              PortMappings:
                - ContainerPort: 5000
              LogConfiguration:
                LogDriver: awslogs
                Options:
                  awslogs-group: !Ref CloudWatchLogsGroup
                  awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Re
  TargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Port: 5000
      Protocol: HTTP
      Matcher:
        HttpCode: 200-299
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 10
      HealthCheckPath: /profile
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 5
      HealthyThresholdCount: 2
```

Given below is the yaml template of the load balancer.

```
Resources:
  LoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref EnvironmentName
      Subnets: !Ref Subnets
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref SecurityGroup
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  LoadBalancerListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref LoadBalancer
      Port: 5000
      Protocol: HTTP
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref DefaultTargetGroup

  # We define a default target group here, as this is a mandatory Parameters
  # when creating an Application Load Balancer Listener. This is not used, instead
  # a target group is created per-service in each service template (../services/*)
  DefaultTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${EnvironmentName}-default
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
```

Given below is the Cloudformation stack.
[image]

Comment: I dont know how you start the application within the container, but I would suggest you'll use forever (https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) to make sure it does not go inactive.

I've had 502 errors because of that in other systems when there were no activity for a few minutes.

Hope this helps a little

Comment: 502 errors are generally caused by NGINX being unable to pass a request to "upstream", in this case your Node.js server (which is also what the error message suggests: "Connection refused"").

It may be crashing and restarting, so check its logfiles to see what's causing the crashes.

Comment: Does the service pass the ECS health check (check the event tab)? Are you sure that the load balancer can connect to the ECS cluster/service (security group settings and/or network ACLs, if set)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error was I didn't had a service listening on port 5000 from the Microservice side. My bad. So, if anyone come across the same. Make sure you have the right image. Also make sure, `ListenerRule` and `TargetGroup` has been set properly.

eg:-

```
TargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      Matcher:
        HttpCode: 200-299
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 10
      HealthCheckPath: /
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 5
      HealthyThresholdCount: 2

  ListenerRule:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
    Properties:
      ListenerArn: !Ref Listener
      Priority: 100
      Conditions:
        - Field: path-pattern
          Values: [ "/*" ]
      Actions:
        - TargetGroupAr
```